# Ios 13 screen brightness problem by swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, uiscreen

I'm working on a project, and I have to control the screen brightness.

I use this to control:

`UIScreen.main.brightness = CGFloat(0.80)`

But, once I lock the screen and unlock, the screen brightness will change back to the system brightness, which could not go back to the brightness which I set before.

If there is any func I can use to change the screen brightness when users unlock the screen?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method called `applicationWillEnterForeground` in `UIApplicationDelegate` which already conforms to your AppDelegate class.
Implement `applicationWillEnterForeground`  by typing name of this method inside your AppDelegate class. like:

you can set the brightness whenever app goes to `foreground`

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
      return true
  }

  func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
      UIScreen.main.brightness = CGFloat(0.80)
  }
}
```

Comment: `applicationWillEnterForeground` is not called under iOS 13 unless your app has completely opted out of using scenes (which it should not do).